# Accidently change Root Ownership - Error 500 : Premature of script headers After header

Tags: linux, root, centos7, whm, ownership

Yesterday I accidently changed root ownership and had all server down, sudo for root was down and all users was down.
I reboot on rescue mode, mount the Disk chroot system and finally restablish ownership and permissions (Not sure about all files and folders default permissions) sudo finally works but all hosted websites shows ERROR 500
Server : VPS ; OS : CENTOS7 ; WHM management system
I restablish folders of accounts hosted owneship but invain
The strangest thing is that when I change ownership of folder of an account all accounts folders ownership changes (I HAVE NEVER SEEN THAT...)
When checked all night long I only got one sign Premature of script headers After header... but I'm not sure it's the main issue
PLEASE HELP, I have a lot of accounts and it's already 24Hours, everyone is compliying

Comment: It is very hard or even impossible to fix it without full knowledge of serveces, users, current mounts and set permissions. I guess you have broken permissions for /var/www. But that's shot in the dark

Comment: Hi Michal, You are right it needs knowledge of many things, but I'm feeling in deep s...t, and can provide any information needed just for help.
Here's the statement of permission and ownership of the file specified :

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 23 root  root   4096 Jan 18 01:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  root   4096 Nov 14 01:01 ../
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 adm/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  root   4096 Mar  3  2017 atlassian/
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root  root   4096 Nov 25  2016 cache/
srw-rw-rw-   1 root  root      0 Jan 18 01:29 clamd=
drwx--x--x  98 root  root  12288 Jan 18 20:05 cpanel/

Comment: drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Oct 19 22:03 crash/
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root  root   4096 Dec  5 00:42 db/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 empty/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 games/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 gopher/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root  root   4096 Aug  4 00:38 kerberos/
drwxr-xr-x. 31 root  root   4096 Sep 14 00:45 lib/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 local/
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root  root     11 Dec 15  2015 lock -> ../run/lock/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  root   4096 Jan 18 19:56 log/

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root     10 Apr 11  2016 mail -> spool/mail/
drwxr-xr-x   6 named named  4096 Jan 18 01:34 named/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 nis/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root  root   4096 Feb  1  2017 opt/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 preserve/
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root  root      6 Dec 15  2015 run -> ../run/
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root  root   4096 Nov 25  2016 spool/
drwxrwxrwt. 19 root  root   4096 Jan 18 19:45 tmp/
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root    163 Nov 25  2016 .updated
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  root   4096 Dec  4 15:21 www/

Comment: drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root   4096 Aug 12  2015 yp/

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you, you need to find a linux guy.

Comment: How about your backups?  You don't necessarily need to restore anything, but if you have backups, you can use them as a reference on what your original permissions were.

Comment: For RPM based distros you can try this https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html